# Is one piece of mother board's all USB ports share power supply?

Tags: motherboard, usb-3

Besides  connecting  several devices to my desktop PC's USB ports , I added one usb hub .Now I want to add another usb hub. My question is whether all usb ports on one mother boards share one power supply? If it's true how much is it ? Do you think i can't connect 2 usb hubs to my PC?(There is 7 ports on mother board and 8 more ports from 2 usb hubs which I want to add a new USB hard drive).

Comment: Even an unpowered hub uses very little current by itself; it's devices plugged into the hub that draw most current. If you use many high-powered USB devices, use a *powered* hub.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to refer to the manufacturer's documentation.
Some mobos share the USB; a single port with several ganged sockets. Some consider each to be a distinct port. [Some are half-way between the two]. There is no hard & fast rule.

This is a picture from my Mac [which does structure things slightly differently, but the same global rules apply]. It shows 8 distinct busses, with hubs hanging from some of those.

As a general rule, and especially if you don't have a powered hub, then hang hard drives directly from a single unique bus, don't go via a hub.

[image]

I'm afraid I don't know how to extract this information on Windows. Device Manager shows my PC to also have 8 busses - however that is more than there are physical headers or ports on the motherboard, even including attached hubs.

[image]